# ¿Cómo usar propiedades de navegación en web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

estoy tratando de consumir una web api hecha con asp.net web api, desde una aplicación de windows forms. Si sólo consumo una tabla, no hay problema. El problema es cuando incluyo tablas relacionadas, ya que como sabemos, genera propiedades de navegación. Tengo el siguiente código:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:54585/") };
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/Expedientes").Result;
        var emp = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<ExpedientePOCO>>().Result;
```

Esto lo utilizo para consumir la api, pero justo en la línea en la que declaro la variable emp, me tira el siguiente error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Se han producido uno o varios errores.
```

y el error que recoje del servidor, es 500 osea un error interno del servidor, asumo que son las propiedades de navegación porque el error empezó al agregar las otras tablas.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno, sé que fue rápido pero encontré la respuesta en otro foro, la dejo por aquí por si a alguien le sirve en su momento, este es el link de dónde encontré la respuesta:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/09d3de8f-03d9-4dbe-bb8f-f71d623774b0/problema-con-web-api-y-entity-framework-debido-a-las-variables-de-navegacin?forum=aspnetmvces

Si usan dbcontext, basta con colocar el siguiente código antes de hacer la consulta:

context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

Espero le sirva a alguien en su momento :D